# AWK: Getting +nan when calculating power of number

Tags: math, awk, floating-point, nan

Problem when using variable

```
echo ""| awk '{
x=-0.35
print x^1.35
print -0.35^1.35
}'
```

Result

```
+nan
-0.242377
```

Using GNU awk

Comment: I get `-nan` rather than `+nan`

Comment: Question is why nan but not -0.24, when substitute x all works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output is **correct**.

The power operator `^` has higher precedence than the negation operator. Therefore, `x^1.35` is `(-0.35)^1.35` (a negative number to a non-integer power is a complex number, interpreted as a `-nan`), but `-0.35^1.35` is `-(0.35^1.35)`, a negated positive power of a positive number.

Comment: Used calc to check the awk and now realized why my calc showed -0.35^(e/2)=-0.24, not error or complex, just because of power higher than negative... Thanks

Comment: @Ivan See my last post.

Answer (score 1):

@Ivan : easiest way to understand why `nan` is to use the `gawk` profiler to show you exactly how `awk` sees your code, and note the `(…)` at last print statement :

---

> ```
> those 5 expressions in 2nd print statement AREN'T all 
> equivalent to each other, just partial subsets among them,
> as seen when plugging in a positive value for x instead
> ```

---

```
gawk -p- -v PREC=65536 -Mbe 'BEGIN { OFMT = "%.37g"; OFS = "\f\r\t"

   for(x = -0.35; x < 1; x += 0.7) { 

      print x, x^1.35, 
                       (-0.35)^1.35 
      print "-----", 
               x^exp(1/2), x^exp(1)^2^-1, x^sqrt(exp(1)), 

            " { -*-*-*-*- }", sqrt(x^exp(1)), x^(exp(1)/2)

      print "———"
      print -(-0.35)^1.35, -0.35^1.35 }  }'
```

---

```
-0.35
    +nan
    +nan
-----
    +nan
    +nan
    +nan
     { -*-*-*-*- }
    +nan
    +nan
------
-nan
    -0.2423772534547380715986015819725977279
```

---

```
0.35
    0.2423772534547380715986015819725977279
    +nan
-----
    0.1771312905039259557488872422384548101
    0.1771312905039259557488872422384548101
    0.1771312905039259557488872422384548101
     { -*-*-*-*- }
    0.2400624449792419477761639194880532529
    0.2400624449792419477761639194880532529
------
-nan
    -0.2423772534547380715986015819725977279
```

---

```
    # gawk profile, created Mon Apr  3 23:18:54 2023

    # BEGIN rule(s)

    BEGIN {
     1      OFMT = "%.37g"
     1      OFS = "\f\r\t"

     2      for (x = -0.35; x < 1; x += 0.7) {

     2          print x, x ^ 1.35, (-0.35) ^ 1.35

     2          print "-----",    x ^ exp(1 / 2), x ^ exp(1) ^ 2 ^ -1, 
                                                  x ^ sqrt( exp(1) ), 
                " { -*-*-*-*- }", 
                                  sqrt(x ^ exp(1)), x ^ (exp(1) / 2)

     2          print "------"
     2          print -(-0.35) ^ 1.35, -(0.35 ^ 1.35)
        }
    }
```